# how to use percentages in java

Tags: java, math, number-formatting, percentage

```
public class BankAccount{
    public int number;
    private double balance;
    public boolean transfer(double amount){
    /*transfer money between BankAccount taking into consideration that a maximum of 50% of the BankAccount      balance can be transferred.*/
    if(amount > 0 && balance >= 50.0){
    balance = balance - amount;
    }
    return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
```

I don't know how to use percentages in java.
so how can i handle the 50% of the balance in percentage?

Comment: If `amount` is a percentage, you can divide it by 100 to convert it to a fraction.

Comment: `amount / balance` - so `50.0 / 100.0` would be `0.5`, as a normalised value (ie `0-1`) would make that `50%`

Comment: By the way, never use [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) for money matters. Use `BigDecimal` class when you need accuracy rather than speed.

Comment: as the word states `per cent` that is `/ 100` - e.g `30%` or `30 percent` is `30 / 100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

50% of a number is its half, so you can use balance / 2 to get 50% of a balance, also consider the initial value of a balance -> if you don't initialize it it will be 0.0 by default (primitive type default value) thus you will always get false for transfer answer. You can try something like this:

```
class BankAccount{
    private double balance = 2000.0;
    
    public boolean transfer(double amount){
        //transfer money between BankAccount taking into consideration
        //that a maximum of 50% of the BankAccount balance can be transferred.
        if(amount > 0 && amount <= balance / 2.0){
            balance = balance - amount;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

In general if you want to get some percent of a number you can multiple number with percentage/100.0
For example:

```
double balance = 1000.0;
double _36_percents_of_balance = balance * 36/100.0;
```

Comment: Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/266284)[When should I edit posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)